# How can I host a temporary video slpash page in front of an exisiting website that links back to the original original homepage

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I have a client that wants to put a video splash page out in front of their current website to highlight a new video they recently produced. This video splash page would have to link through to the original website of course, but the client wants the video splash page to be what visitors see when they visit the site URL.

My thoughts so far are this:

Place the video splash page inside the existing site structure under a subfolder. As the hosting service to redirect to that subfolder's index.html when the URL is visited.

However, how would I then link back to the original webpage from the splash page if there is a redirect in place?